# Is it normal for valid ruby code to be high lighted red in intellij?

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea

Is the following valid ruby code? Intellij doesnt think so. Ive filed a ticket with intellij but I want to make sure my codes ok.

I know it wont do anything but intellij is telling me attr_reader is unknown so I am confused.

```
class Person
  attr_reader :first_name, :last_name

  def initialize
    @first_name = nil
    @last_name = nil
  end
end
```

The reason Im asking is that intellij is highlighting attr_reader as red which typicaly is a syntax error. I spend all my time doing Java and Scala so I'm a bit lost with ruby. Is it normal for valid code to be high lighted red?

Comment: You've asked the wrong question. As stated, the answer is "yes" and the reference to 'intellij-idea' is irrelevant. You need to change the question and provide more information.

Comment: Thanks Cary. My initial question I'm comfortable with as I had no idea. I'll expand now I know my code is valid.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using RubyMine and it has a built-in editor. All is fine with your code, just I don't see a point in initializing `@first_name` and `@last_name` to nil. Instance variables, the moment you call them, they are set to nil. Try this:

```
class Person
  attr_reader :first_name, :last_name

  def initialize
    p @first_name
    p @last_name
    p first_name #=> the method attr_reader created which returns @first_name
    p last_name #=> the other method it created which returns @last_name
    p @i_can_set_up_any_variable_i_want_here
  end
end

Person.new #=> it will print 'nil' 5 times.
```

So you can freely remove the code inside initialize. Actually, you can remove the whole initialize method altogether, because every instance variable, doesn't matter from where you first reference it, will evaluate to nil, unlike with local variables which will produce an error.

Comment: thanks dare. I guess something is broken with my install of rubymine :(

Comment: Try doing File > Invalidate Caches / Restart and select the first option.

Comment: not only can remove the code in `initialize`. You can remove the entire method definition

Answer (score 0):

Assigning instance variables to nil to "initialize" them is not necessary.  When you first reference an instance variable it is already "initialized" to nil.  It doesn't even need to be called.

See this example:

```
if false    # => false
  @example
end         # => nil

p @example  # => nil
```

And `attr_reader :name`, for example, will reference `@name` and will automatically be assigned `nil` until it is assigned something else.